# Parsing and extracting variables from math/algebraic expression

Tags: regex

Given a string representing a math expression

```
(((x + temp) * temp_2) / 2_temp) + x3
```

I need to extract all the variables, except numbers and operators.
Only round brackets are permitted.
In particular, valid variables that can be extracted are:

```
x
x23
x_23
2_temp
2temp
2_
temp
temp_2
temp
```

but not

```
2
15
```

So, in general, any variable can start with any character but, if it starts with a number, then it must contain at least one letter.

I've tried this regex expression

```
matcher=Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\w*?[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\w*?)").matcher(equation);
```

but, for example, 15 is extracted.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you seem to want to extract entities starting with an alphanumeric and then having 0+ word chars.

You may use

```
\b(?!\d+\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]\w*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/526ScE/1)

If you allow these variables to start with an underscore, just use `\b(?!\d+\b)\w+\b`.

The point here is that the `(?!\d+\b)` negative lookahead does not allow the string between word boundaries to only contain digits.

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!\d+\b)` - restriction: there must be no 1+ digits followed with a word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric (in Java, you may also use `\p{Alnum}`)
- `\w*` - 0 or more word chars
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

In Java, do not forget to use double backslashes when defining a pattern:

```
String pat = "\\b(?!\\d+\\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]\\w*\\b";
```

Comment: Have I use matcher.group(0) to get the result?

Comment: Yes, the `.group(0)` will hold the entire match value.

Answer (score 0):

An alphanumeric string that contains at least one letter:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```